# Facebook Rewarded video ad failed to load

Tags: android, facebook, rewardedvideoad

I am trying to integrate Facebook rewarded video. but while getting placement id there is no placement for Rewarded video. there are only Native, banner, Interstitial and Medium Rectangle.I am using those steps from [facebook docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/android/rewarded-video)

my logcat give this error:

> 05-25 18:27:22.530 6932-6932 
>   Rewarded video ad failed to load: The display format in the ad request
>   does not match the display format specified for this placement. Each
>   placement can only be used with a single display format. You can
>   create multiple placements in order to use multiple display formats.

Comment: @mehmat did you got the solution..? Because i am facing the exact problem. If yes, Please share it here

Comment: beacuse of character limit. I put the answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually the problem still live. and this is email from developer team

Hello,

Thank you for writing into Audience Network. Rewarded video is a whitelisted ad format. There are four requirements you must meet before you can apply:

1. You must have the Audience Network SDK integrated in your game
2. Your app must have an active, approved Audience Network account with payment information.
3. Game only: Your game app is active and added to your account.
4. Ad position: You must already have a rewarded video ad unit in your game.

If you fit the criteria, please submit your information so that we may review it:

App ID:
Link to the App Store

You will be contacted should there be a good fit.

Best,

Audience Network Team

Comment: This doesn't really help me. I don't have a game and I already have running banner ads from Facebook in my app and get paid but yet I still get the above mentioned error. Any other solution or things I have to consider?

Comment: So, Rewarded video ad is only for games?